# how to get excel sheet name using datatable in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am using the following code to get data from excel sheet:-

```
private static DataTable GetDataFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
        using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
        {
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
            foreach (string column in colFields)
            {
                DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
            }
            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                //Making empty value as null
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fieldData[i] == "")
                    {
                        fieldData[i] = null;
                    }
                }
                csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
            }
            return csvData;
        }
    }
```

but I need to retrieve same from sheets within same workbook. Any idea how can I do this using datatable in c#.

Thanks

Comment: Are you reading excel file or csv? Csv is just plain text, no?

Comment: How is this related to NUnit?

Comment: Your code suggests the file you are parsing is just a plain text CSV file.  If that is the case, then there is no tab names to get

Comment: @lavrik: I am reading excel file. removed the nunit bit as I am calling that code in nunit tests. Reading data from excel sheet to get input for nunit tests. Currently I have to read 4 excel files instead I want to merge it in one excel file and move data in sheets. is it possible?

Comment: `A file associated to be open with excel` is not necessarily an excel file - have a look at the file extension (that is why i don't like the windows explorer option *hide file extension for known file types*). :-)

Comment: yes, its definitely a excel file. As users input data in Excel sheets

Comment: This may sound stupid, but is this the right code segment? `TextFieldParser` can't make its way through an Excel file. Regardless, the `Workbook` contains a `.Worksheets` collection and each `Worksheet` in the collection has a `.Name` member, which is the name that you see on the tab.

Comment: "As users input data in Excel sheets" doesn't mean input into xls or xlsx file. It may mean that users use MS Excel to edit CSV. You can create excel file with data from 4 source csv files and read a new single file, but you need another API, not TextFieldParser. To read new xlsx files i use DocumentFormat.OpenXml assembly.

Answer (score 0):

"As users input data in Excel sheets" doesn't mean input into xls or xlsx file. It may mean that users use MS Excel to edit CSV. You can create "true excel" file with data from 4 source csv files and read a new single file, but you need another API, not TextFieldParser. To read new xlsx files i use DocumentFormat.OpenXml assembly. Quick sample is

```
      using (var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(_docPath, false))
      {
            var sheet = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>().First()
            //Or iterate over all sheets, get sheet name, read it's data etc.
            //i'm sure you can find a lot of samples 
            var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
            var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            foreach (var row in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
            {
                    //some code here
            }
      }
```